# Fetch content inside the <title> tag

Tags: asp.net, html, metadata, meta-tags

I am developing a web application using ASP.Net 4.0. I am trying to read the metadata as well as text inside a tag.
I am able to get the meta tag value but not the text inside a simple tag. It returns a value if it is inside a meta tag, otherwise not. But I would like to fetch both the meta tag and `<title>` tag.

Comment: your question isn't clear, could you explain with an example?

Comment: If you're trying to parse HTML (I suppose that's what you're doing), try the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), it saves you a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have runat="server" on your head tag, like this :

```
<head runat="server">
```

then you will be able to access meta tags with code behind like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control cnt in Page.Header.Controls)
  {
    if (cnt is HtmlMeta)
    {
      HtmlMeta meta = cnt as HtmlMeta;
      Response.Write("Meta tag name: " + meta.Name + ", content: " + meta.Content + ", http-equiv:" + meta.HttpEquiv + "<br />");          
    }

    if (cnt is HtmlTitle)
    {
      HtmlTitle tit = cnt as HtmlTitle;
      Response.Write("Title : " + tit.Text + "<br />");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for being brave enough to name your variable like this! ;-)

Comment: :)) well, english is not my native language, and I did't realize it, supose that I can't change this now since I will loose my upvote

Comment: Maybe also just my dirty mind, lol.. anyway don't worry my upvote will stick, your answer is correct and good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for achieve what you want.

You have to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to namespace

```
protected string GetTagText(string source, string tag)
{
    var regexStr = string.Format("(?<=<{0}>).*(?=</{0}>)", tag);
    Regex regex = new Regex(regexStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (regex.IsMatch(source))
    {
        return regex.Match(source).Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Use like

```
GetTagText("<title>test title</title>", "title");
```

returns `test title`